# How to change the custom options price

Tags: price, custom-options

i want to change the custom options price programmatically. below is code that i want to Change.

```
var opConfig = new Product.Options({"38":{"86":{"price":152,"oldPrice":152,"priceValue":"152.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":152,"includeTax":152},"87":{"price":255,"oldPrice":255,"priceValue":"255.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":255,"includeTax":255},"88":{"price":655,"oldPrice":655,"priceValue":"655.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":655,"includeTax":655},"89":{"price":755,"oldPrice":755,"priceValue":"755.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":755,"includeTax":755},"90":{"price":955,"oldPrice":955,"priceValue":"955.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":955,"includeTax":955},"91":{"price":1200,"oldPrice":1200,"priceValue":"1200.0000","type":"fixed","excludeTax":1200,"includeTax":1200}}});
```

i want to change the price in this array how can i do that which file i need to rewrite to change price please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do a bit of digging or are you just waiting for an answer?